# How to know if url is already bookmarked

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarks

I am adding bookmark from code. Now in Firefox if user already added the url as bookmark he should not be able to bookmark it again. How can I do it? For now every time a new bookmark is getting created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent people from clicking a bookmark link on your website for a second time, you could try to write using cookies to hide the link if there's a cookie on the client.

As far as I know trying to check the bookmarks library (Places) in FireFox by using javascript on your website, that is impossible.

Comment: Yh. I will try that option if nothing easier found. :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you cannot, except for the above two good suggestions: use cookies. Or user information (although if they registered, they probably already bookmarked the site!).
Cookie solution is brittle, though, as user can erase them.

Why you cannot: that would be an obvious security breach if a JavaScript program could read the list of bookmarks of the user: beside privacy concerns, one can have some sensible information in the URL parameters...

Side note: adding a bookmark is done on user action (or should be!). So users should know if they added the bookmark already, no?

Comment: Right. But what sometimes happens that user forgets that he has added it in his bookmarks. In IE it gives an alert that bookmark already present.

Comment: But that's browser based. The website did not alert the user, IE did.

Comment: @in-spite: I confusedly felt the word was wrong! :-P Thanks for correcting. Sensible is actually the French word... :-)

Answer (score 1):

[getBookmarkIdsForURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsINavBookmarksService#getBookmarkIdsForURI())

*"This method retrieves the list of bookmark IDs that contain the given URI."*

Comment: Does it need any library or something to add? If yes how to.

Comment: Interesting, and good solution for the privacy issue. But that's for extensions only, no?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, try setting a cookie whenever the user bookmarks your site using your Javascript.  If the cookie exists, remove the bookmark button (or whatever).